# Uncaught TypeError: jPanelMenu.close is not a function

Tags: typeerror

After moving wordpress to another server i have a problem with js. The mobile menu dont work. Here is the address of the website. http://romfordremovals.co.uk/

I'm not a specialist. I ask for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray character 's' on line 190 of your main.js file. You have several 404 errors also , clear those up also then you will see fewer errors in the console.